# Is there any way to do a "Replace Or Insert" using web.config transformation?

Tags: asp.net, web-config-transform, xslt, xdt-transform

I'm using web.config transformation as described in the below post in order to generate configs for different environments.

http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/03/web-deployment-webconfig-transformation_23.html

I can do a "Replace" transformation by matching on the key, e.g.

```
<add key="Environment" value="Live" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
```

And I can do "Inserts" e.g.

```
<add key="UseLivePaymentService" value="true" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
```

But what I would *really* find useful is a ReplaceOrInsert transformation, as I can't always rely on the original config file having/not having a certain key.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: the link you provided is not working as of now. Do you have any other link to understand the concept easily?

Comment: @AshishJain the link works fine for me

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I found a cheap workaround.  It ain't pretty and won't work very well if you have a lot of elements that needs to be "Replace Or Insert".

Do a "Remove" and then an "InsertAfter|InsertBefore".

For example,

```
<authorization xdt:Transform="Remove" />
<authorization xdt:Transform="InsertAfter(/configuration/system.web/authentication)">
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: If using VS2012, there's now a better solution. See below http://stackoverflow.com/a/16679201/32055

Comment: will "InsertIfMissing" Insert And Replace if needed?

Comment: I prefer this option over the other one thanks to the use of InsertAfter.  InsertIfMissing makes no sense if you're doing a Remove anyway.

Answer (score 144):

In conjunction with `xdt:Transform="Remove"` use `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"` in VS2012.

```
<authorization xdt:Transform="Remove" />
<authorization xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what we've been waiting for.

Comment: Is there a similar "InsertAfterIfMissing"?

Comment: This does not do as OP requests, at all.

Comment: The answer has been edited to more clearly demonstrate how it does answer the original question.

Comment: I don't get it. If you remove it, of course it's going to be missing, it's just an Insert at that point, right?

Comment: @ChadSchouggins not necessarily: the `Remove` task only removes the first occurrence. Some elements can have multiple occurrences. I can't imagine that you would want this, but then it would remove the first occurrence and skip the `InsertIfMissing` task. But you would have been right if he used `RemoveAll` instead.

Comment: @ChadSchouggins I think this ended up like that due to the history of this answer which never actually answered the OP's question to begin with, the original answer her simply suggested to use InsertIfMissing which would not cover the "Replace" part, here Remove or RemoveAll becomes crucial. I don't get why Bon did not just add an actual answer him self instead of editing this into an answer that it ends up giving a solution, that would have been more appropriate IMO. I think your right that Remove -> Insert would have been the best fit for the OP. And then add Remove vs RemoveAll caveat.

Answer (score 102):

Use the `InsertIfMissing` transformation to ensure that the appSetting exists.
Then use the `Replace` transformation to set its value.

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="Environment" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  <add key="Environment" value="Live" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

You could also use the `SetAttributes` transformation instead of `Replace`. The difference is  that `SetAttributes` does not touch child nodes.

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="UseLivePaymentService" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
  <add key="UseLivePaymentService" value="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

These techniques are much better than remove+insert because existing nodes are not moved to the bottom of their parent node. New nodes are appended at the end. Existing nodes stay where they are in the source file.

This answer applies only to newer versions of Visual Studio (2012 or newer).

Answer (score 8):

A better method for me was to insert the element only if it doesn't exist since I am only setting certain attributes. Removing the element would discard any other attributes of the main element if they existed.

example:
web.config (without element)

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Wcf.ServiceImplementation.AllDigitalService_Behavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

web.config (with element)

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="Wcf.ServiceImplementation.AllDigitalService_Behavior">
        <serviceDebug httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" />
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Using the Locator with an XPath expression, I add the node if it doesn't exist and then set my attribute:

```
<serviceDebug xdt:Transform="Insert"
  xdt:Locator="XPath(/configuration/system.serviceModel/behaviors/serviceBehaviors/behavior[not(serviceDebug)])" />
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
```

both resulting web.config files have includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" and the second one preserves the httpsHelpPageEnabled attribute where the remove/insert method would not.

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm getting an error if the element already exists "No element in the source document matches...". That is, if it exists, the "not" is failing, so it's an error.

Comment: This is the technique you need when you're using versions of XDT that don't support the new(ish) "InsertIfMissing" element.