# My web.config transformations are not having any effect when I publish my Blazor WASM site to a third party host using Visual Studio publish wizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, hosting, blazor-webassembly

My web.config transformations are not having any effect when I publish my site to my third party host from Visual Studio 2019's publish wizard.

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application and three environments: Development, Staging and Production.

In `MyProject\Properties\PublishProfiles` I have a `.pubxml` file each for Staging and Production on a third party hosting provider. (I don't need a `.pubxml` for Development because I plan on only running that on my local development PC.

Here is what `Staging.pubxml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <EnvironmentName>Staging</EnvironmentName>
        <WebPublishMethod>FTP</WebPublishMethod>
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>staging.myproject.com</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <ProjectGuid>12c14c2e-4d13-4e23-bf64-8e92faf909e9</ProjectGuid>
        <publishUrl>ftp.hostingprovider.net</publishUrl>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
        <FtpPassiveMode>True</FtpPassiveMode>
        <FtpSitePath>myproject-blazor-stag</FtpSitePath>
        <UserName>myloginname</UserName>
        <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I would like to insert the following in the `<configuration>` element of my `web.config` file whenever the project is published using the `Staging.pubxml` profile:

```
<system.webServer>
   <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
         <add name="blazor-environment" value="Staging" />
      </customHeaders>
   </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-5.0#set-the-environment-via-header

I should be able to do it using a `web.config` transformation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig?view=aspnetcore-5.0

So, in my project root directory I added an XML tranformation called `Web.Staging.config`
Here's the content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
   <location>
      <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
         <httpProtocol xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <customHeaders xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
               <add name="blazor-environment" value="Staging"
                    xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
                    xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
            </customHeaders>
         </httpProtocol>
      </system.webServer>
   </location>
</configuration>
```

I was expecting that, when I publish my site using the `Staging.pubxml` profile, this `Web.Staging.config` transformation would add the missing section to the `web.config` file deployed to the third party host. Then, when I load up the Blazor application in a browser, it should be using the settings for the Staging environment. Unfortunately, the transformation is never applied to the `web.config` file. I downloaded the file to check, and nothing had been added. Thefore, the Blazor app runs using the settings of the Production environment instead of Staging.

Can anybody see what I did wrong, please?

EDIT: There is now a [minimal reproducible sample on my GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35584).

Comment: I think that after `system.webserver` you need to add `<aspNetCore>` before `<httpProtocol>`. Try it.

Comment: Hi @NicolaBiada! Thank you for the suggestion! I have given it a try but it produced invalid XML according to that schema. <httpProtocol> is not valid inside <aspNetCore>

Comment: Yes, my bad, sorry! Look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15102834/web-config-transforms-insert-if-not-exists.  Someone says that you need `xdt:Locator="Match(path)` on every `InsertIfMissing` to work as expected.

Comment: The answer you linked to has a really useful tool for testing transformation files so I'm going to mention it here http://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/ It helped me ascertain that I should not have a <location> tag (thank you). But it's still not working.

Comment: I also learned (here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/web-config-transformations) that you can right-click on any transformation .config file in VS and go to Preview Transform to see what the result of the transformation would be. This is really helpful and proves that I would now get exactly what I want *IF* the transformation got applied. But it's not getting applied for some reason.

Comment: Ok Benjamin, later I'll give it a try.

Comment: Wow, that would be great if you have time, thank you, Nicola. If you do, there is a minimal reproducible sample on my GitHub issue, linked here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35584

Comment: After a LOT of attempts I can confirm that transformation works as expected in an MVC project but __NOT__ in an Webassembly project. The only possibility is to use the `<PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>` parameters but it only copy the web.config from the project to the publishing folder, without transformations.

Comment: Wow, @NicolaBiada, thank you for persevering! I really appreciate it. That's not good news - I was hoping it would be my fault so I could fix it! So I guess it's some kind of bug unique to deploying Blazor WASM applications.

Comment: I think that a possible workaround in the meantime could be a transformation during build. But after a lot attempts I haven't found any real working solution. If you are interested I can share this process.

Comment: That could work. I guess you mean like a SlowCheetah sort of solution, where whatever build configuration you select is used to choose a web.{BuildConfiguration}.config and transform a template of web.config file at build time?

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm trying to use only the Vs tools without any additional Nugent/tools but it seems the system copy the file without any transformation.

Comment: Solution in the answer Benjamin. 
Evaluate to shorten the title with something more "direct" to the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Nicola. Like you, I also try to use as few extra tools as possible, but this will solve the problem until (hopefully) a fix is deployed in Blazor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're transformation is possible via **SlowCheetah** NuGet package.
This package is under Microsoft Dotnet Foundation, so I can confirm that is currently supported on the latest stable version of Visual Studio projects, including Blazor WASM.

### Solution

**TheProject.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishIISAssets>true</PublishIISAssets>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Staging</Configurations>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.9" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.9" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah" Version="3.2.26">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="web.config">
      <TransformOnBuild>True</TransformOnBuild>
    </None>
    <None Include="web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
    <None Include="web.Staging.config">
      <DependentUpon>web.config</DependentUpon>
      <IsTransformFile>True</IsTransformFile>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**web.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".blat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dat" />
      <remove fileExtension=".dll" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <remove fileExtension=".wasm" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".blat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dll" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".dat" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".wasm" mimeType="application/wasm" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <add mimeType="application/octet-stream" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/wasm" enabled="true" />
      </dynamicTypes>
    </httpCompression>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**web.Release.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <httpProtocol xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <customHeaders xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
          <add name="blazor-environment" value="Prod"
               xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
               xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**web.Staging.config**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
    <httpProtocol xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <customHeaders xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="blazor-environment" value="Staging"
             xdt:Locator="Match(name)"
             xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've created two Publishing Profile, one for *Release* and one for *Staging* and both work as expected.

The *web.config* will be available in the `bin\Staging\net5.0\browser-wasm\publish` folder if you publish to a folder.

#### Note

Thanks to SlowCheetah your transformations will be applied in the **Build** process, not only in the **Publishing** process.

So you'll can find your transformed *web.config* in the *output* folder, like `bin\Staging\net5.0`