# How to handle deep XDT transforms when structure of target config file is not known?

Tags: xml, nuget, web-config-transform, xdt-transform

I am trying to create a web.config installer for my NuGet package using XDT Transforms.

I want to transform web.config file:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

to look like this:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*." verb="*" type="CustomHandler" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

---

Here are the transforms I have tried:

**Transform #1:**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add path="*." verb="*" type="CustomHandler" xdt:Transform="Insert" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This only works if the target web.config already contains a `<httpHandlers />` section.

In the above example (note, there is no `<httpHandlers />` section), this results in an error:

> No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.web/httpHandlers/add'

**Transform #2:**

```
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers xdt:Transform="Insert">
            <add path="*." verb="*" type="CustomHandler" />
        </httpHandlers>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This works as expected in the above example, but given a web.config file with a pre-existing `<httpHandlers />` section, that section is duplicated.

Remember, this is for a NuGet package and I can't make assumptions about the state of user's config.

I am new to XDT Transforms, so may have missed something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like [this will do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16679201).

New in VS2012, `xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing"`.

Comment: Sadly, there is no corresponding xdt:Transform="RemoveIfEmpty" to do the reverse.

Comment: Well, they did open source it... You could write your own! http://xdt.codeplex.com/